# BGL: Is it possible to use range for of C++11 to loop over the vertices of the graph?

Tags: c++, boost

This question is about the `Boost Graph Library`.

How (if at all possible) can one use the *range for* loop of C++11 to loop over the vertices of the graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, with a little bit of coding.

Let's first recap how to access the vertices of a graph in bgl. If the graph `g` implements the [VertexListGraph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/graph/doc/VertexListGraph.html) concept, then you can call `vertices(g)` which will return a `std::pair<vertex_iterator, vertex_iterator>`.

Now, you can't use a pair as a range, but boost has a helper for you: [iterator_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html)

Untested example code:

```
for(auto& vertex : make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For any object, you can overload the non-member `std::begin` and `std::end`, as long as the object provides an iterator of some sort. Knowing that, any object can be compatible with range based loops.